# UINavigationBar.barTintColor issues on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, iphone-4, bartintcolor

I'm customizing the barTintColor of my app's UINavigationBar and UIToolbar like this: 
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

This works on iPhone5+ and in the simulator, but when I run the app on iPhone4 (iOS7), the `UINavigationBar` becomes completely clear as soon as I transition to another view with `pushViewController`.

The same issues occur when I manipulate `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor` instead of `UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor`.

I can partly avoid the problem by not setting the `barTintColor` at all, but that approach limits me to the default barTintColor and it sometimes flips to a black background on iPhone4.

How can I reliably customize barTintColor on iPhone 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to have been a bug, it has been resolved with iOS 7.0.3